# extending remote desktop connection without changing admin password

Tags: remote-desktop, remote, login-screen

I want to know how to extend my remote connection time ( it disconnects in 3 minutes of idle time). And the remote desktop is protected by a password.

Answer (score 0):

Its controlled from the server in the group/local policy editor (gpedit.msc). Navigate to:  `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Session Time Limits` and enable each policy and set your desired timeouts.